I have migrated the application from java 1.8 to java 17 but in some export functionalities I'm not able to get a excel file leads to a error
The error is

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(java.lang.Object)'
at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.(SharedStringsTable.java:92) ~[poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar:3.10.1]

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

What versions of the dependencies will be compatible to java 17 with spring boot 2.7.9?

Apache POI 3.10 was released back in 2014, what happens if you upgrade to something that isn't over a decade old?
